# How do you iterate over all methods in a JavaScript pseudoclass, regardless of whether or not they are marked enumerable?

Tags: javascript, methods, iteration, pseudo-class, members

I'm trying to iterate over all methods in a JavaScript pseudoclass and can easily tell if something is a method or not with (obj.member instanceof Function), however I'm trying to include methods that may be hidden from a for...in loop via defineProperty with an enumerable flag set to false - how do I iterate all members of a pseudoclass, regardless of the enumerable value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames), which will include non-enumerable properties as well. However, this will not include properties from prototypes, so if you are asking about "pseudoclass instances" you might need to [loop the prototype chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30158566/1048572) with [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).

Comment: Correction, in 8 minutes you can have some karma - damned site think's I'm a bot or something.

Comment: what if, in inspection, I can see a property but it doesn't apear under `getOwnPropertyNames` nor `keys`? Example: `typeof obj['stuff'] == 'function'; Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).indexOf('stuff') == -1`. This happened on an ES6 class, babelified.

Comment: @igorsantos07: as the answer says, it's likely an inherited property. Try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))`, or use a complete loop.

Comment: whoa. that's confusing. it seems from the object instance I need to use getPrototypeOf to get to the actual defined class. might be some sort of effect from using Babel to transpile code :|

Comment: @igorsantos07: No, that's how prototypes worked since the beginning, even without ES6 or Babel.

Comment: so getOwnPropertyNames won't include properties from prototypes nor properties defined by its own class, right?

Comment: @igorsantos07 I'm not sure what you mean by "its own class". Every instance inherits the shared class methods from the prototype object. Only instance-specific data is stored in own properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121685/discussion-between-igorsantos07-and-bergi).

Comment: The [following link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) might be relevant here.