# JavaScript: How to get child Class's methods in parent's constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, constructor

How to get (`console.log` for ex.) `B` class's methods in `A` class's constructor?

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        // GET B's method names ('ok', ...) here
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    ok() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a big code smell

Comment: what is the benefit and what sense?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest just wondering if I can do auto-bindings ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "base" constructor you have access to complete object, so can check what is its real constructor and so its prototype `const childClassPrototype = this.constructor.prototype`. Having a "child" prototype you can get a list of its properties with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(childClassPrototype)`. From that list you want to filter out "constructor" and properties that are not functions.

Note: this technique will only give you access to "leaf" prototype, once you may have a multi level prototype chain. Thus you have to iterate over prototype chain.

Note2: for autobinding you may like to consider using a decorator. One implementation is here: https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator - this technique gives you better control over unexpected behavior that may come from metaprogramming

Comment: Thanks. this Works better :)

Answer (score 1):

Use either `new.target.prototype` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` to get the prototype object of the instantiated subclass. Then [traverse the prototype chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30158566/1048572) to all superclasses, and get the own properties of each object. Don't forget non-enumerable properties.

Of course, using this in a constructor for more than logging/debugging purposes is a code smell. A class should not need to know about its subclasses. If you want to do autobindings, let each subclass constructor autobind its own methods.