# Is there a method that returns all properties of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The `Object.keys(obj)` returns the own enumerable properties of the object this is analogous to `Object.hasOwnProperty()` which are true. What I am looking for is a function that would give all properties even from the prototype chain

Comment: `for in` will loop over every property in the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over all properties of an object:

```js
var myObject = {ownProp: 1};

for (let prop in myObject) {
        console.log(prop);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used it and created 
`Object.allKeys = function(o){
 var arr = [];
 for (let prop in o) {
        arr.push(prop);
 }
 return arr;
}`  hope this is correct.

Comment: @Neelotpal Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158515/list-down-all-prototype-properties-of-an-javascript-object).  There's no built-in method for it.

Bergi's suggestion:  *(Using `.getPrototypeOf()` to traverse up the prototype chain and recursively get the properties of every object)*

```js
var myObj = {ownProp1:1, ownProp2:2};

function logAllProperties(obj) {
     if (obj == null) return; // recursive approach
     console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
     logAllProperties(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
}
logAllProperties(myObj);
```