# Serializing Coordinates: Object.keys() fails on instances of native interfaces?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have some JavaScript running in Chrome using the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition):

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((pos) => {
    console.log(pos.coords);
    console.log(Object.keys(pos.coords);

  }, (err) => {
    alert('Geolocation error.\n' + err.message);

  }, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  });
```

When Chrome detects a change in location, it fires off the first callback.  This is working well.

The problem comes when I try to do something with that data.  When the callback is fired, on my console I will first be able to see the Coordinates object where I called `console.log(pos.coords)`:

> Coordinates {latitude: 5.520007, longitude: 13.404954, altitude: null, accuracy: 150, altitudeAccuracy: null, …}

However, the next line where I call `console.log(Object.keys(pos.coords))`, I get an empty array:

> []

Likewise, if I try to use `JSON.stringify(pos.coords)`, I just get an empty object `{}`.

Is there any reasonable way to loop through the keys of `pos.coords`?  Must I make my own list of keys to loop through?

Comment: Try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` (if they're not enumerable for some reason)? Or traverse the prototype chain to find getters.

Comment: @Bergi `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(pos.coords)` also comes up as an empty array.

Comment: Seems there's an NPM package for this!  https://github.com/zeke/geoposition-to-object  With a hard-coded list of properties:  https://github.com/zeke/geoposition-to-object/blob/master/index.js  Strange.

Comment: Could be that they're "getter" functions defined on the prototype. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(pos.coords.__proto__);` You can traverse them like this if so: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(pos.coords.__proto__)
  .forEach(p => console.log(pos.coords[p]))`

Comment: @spanky That seems to be it.  I suppose this is just an implementation quirk.  I don't know what they'll throw in there in the future, so I think I'll just reduce a whitelist of properties for now.

Comment: @Brad Then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30158566/1048572), please. They must be somewhere… (OK, it's a host object that could work like a proxy, but I can't see any reason for that)

Comment: @Bergi If you or spanky want to post an answer explaining this behavior, I'd be happy to mark it as an answer.  Even better if you have a guess as to why they did it this way.  :-)  Thanks.

Comment: they are not "own" props, they are inherited. \

Comment: @Brad I suspect they're getters that access the internal native data representation. Btw, does `for … in` work? They might still be enumerable.

Comment: @Bergi `for … in` does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Object.keys(pos.coords)` gets an empty array

Yes, the properties of the [`Coordinates`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Coordinates) interface are implemented as getters on the prototype object (instead of own properties), so `Object.keys` doesn't find them.

> Is there any reasonable way to loop through the keys of pos.coords?

You can in fact just loop through them:

```
for (const p in pos.coords)
    console.log(p);
```

An alternative is to use

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(pos.coords));
```

> Do you have a guess as to why they did it this way?

I suspect they're getters that access the internal native data representation linked from the host object. That way, they're implicitly readonly as [the spec for the interface](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#coordinates) requires. They should have been able to achieve that by simply making them own, non-writable data properties either, though.