# Object.getOwnPropertyNames in an array but includes the main attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've been using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` for a while. This is my code:

```
var ObjectAdditions = {
    deepFreeze: function(o) {//code},
    extendToArray: function(object) {//code}
};
var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ObjectAdditions);
```

This is what `properties` came up as:

```
["deepFreeze", "extendToArray"]
```

Unfortunately I also expected attributes like "prototype" and "constructor" to come up. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List Down All Prototype Properties of an Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158515/list-down-all-prototype-properties-of-an-javascript-object)

Comment: I don't mean the properties of the prototype, I mean the prototype itself

Answer (score 0):

Your `ObjectAdditions` is just a simple object with `deepFreeze` and `extendToArray` as properties. It is not a class.

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames` with classes looks like this:

```js
class MyClass {
  // the cunstructer doesn't apper anywhere else than as MyClass() itself. It is only callable with "new".
  constructor() {
    // this will be added as a property to the instance
    this.myInstanceAttribute = null;
  }
  // this will be added as a property to the class
  static myStaticFunction() {}
  // this will be added to the prototype
  myInstanceFunction() {}
}
MyClass.myStaticAttribute = null;

// shows the class prototype and name, the statics and length from the constructor-function (numer of expected parameters) 
console.log('class', Object.getOwnPropertyNames( MyClass ));

// only the added "myInstanceAttribute"
console.log('instance', Object.getOwnPropertyNames( new MyClass() ));
```