# Unable to access exception properties in v8 runtime

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, v8, google-apps-script-runtime

I am trying to get the stack trace (and other details) when an exception occurs in my code. To do this the following piece of code use to work:

```js
function catchException() {
  
  var errLog = [];
  
  try {
    
    var temp;
    temp.split(",");
    
  } catch (exception) {
    
    for (var property in exception) {
      
      errLog.push(property + ": " + exception[property]);
    }
    
  }
  
  return errLog;
}
```

But ever since the v8 runtime update on Google Apps Script, this doesn't return any property of the exception object.

In v8 runtime, I can get the stack trace in the above code, if I use `exception["stack"]`, I get the stack trace.

But I was hoping I could avoid using the string (`"stack"`) and also get all the other properties of the exception for which I might not know the property name.

The `for...in` loop doesn't seem to be working in this scenario.

**How can I access the exception object's properties?**

(all the properties without using the property names)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for..in` only enumerates properties that are configured as enumerable; an exception's "stack" property is not enumerable (you can check with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(exception, "stack")`). You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to get all property names of an object, enumerable or not:

```
let keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(exception);
for (let key of keys) {
  console.log(key + ": " + exception[key]);
}
```

Note that, as the name implies, this lists an object's *own* properties. If you're also interested in properties inherited from its prototypes, you can use a loop to iterate the prototype chain:

```
function DumpAllProperties(o) {
  let receiver = o;
  while (o) {
    for (let key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
      console.log(key + " -> " + receiver[key]);
    }
    o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might have been expecting the properties that were previously present in Errors, `Error.fileName` and `Error.lineNumber` are no longer supported in V8. There is instead `Error.prototype.stack`. which would not show up under the iterable properties of Error.

To iterate over the Error prototype properties, you can follow the code in this answer: [List Down All Prototype Properties of an Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158515/list-down-all-prototype-properties-of-an-javascript-object)

The changes to the Error object are mentioned in [this section of their V8 migration guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#avoid_using_errorfilename_and_errorlinenumber).

> In the V8 runtime, the standard JavaScript Error object doesn't support
>   the `fileName` or `lineNumber` as constructor parameters or object
>   properties.
>
> When migrating your script to V8, remove any dependence on
>   `Error.fileName` and `Error.lineNumber`.
>
> An alternative is to use the `Error.prototype.stack`. This stack is also
>   non-standard, but supported in both Rhino and V8.