# what's the best way to check if one object is a prototype of another?

Tags: javascript

I believe the best way would be something like:

```
var a = {a:1, b:2}
var b = Object.create(a);
b.a = 1
var c = Object.create(b);
c.c = 3;
var d = Object.create(c);

d.protoTree();  //returns: [c, b, a]
c.protoTree();  //returns: [b, a];
b.protoTree();  //returns: [a];
```

But is this possible? What's the best way assuming you only know the D object?

Comment: [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30158566/1048572

Comment: Your code seems to do something different than what your question asks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wouldn't be good to have that as a member method, but it's easy to implement as a standalone (recursive) function:

```
function protoTree(obj){
    if(obj === null) return []
    return [obj, ...protoTree(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))]
}
```

It works like this (note that it also returns `Object.prototype`, that `a` inherits from.

```
var a = {a:1, b:2}
var b = Object.create(a);
b.a = 1
var c = Object.create(b);
c.c = 3;
var d = Object.create(c);

//Note that `protoTree` returns the prototype objects themselves, not the variable names they are stored in
protoTree(d);  //returns: [c, b, a, Object.prototype]
protoTree(c);  //returns: [b, a, Object.prototype]
protoTree(b);  //returns: [a, Object.prototype]
protoTree(a);  //returns: [Object.prototype]
```

Comment: this spreading operator bugged my mind.

Comment: @RafaeldeSouza `[obj, ...protoTree(...)]`  will create an array of `obj` and all the values returned by the recursive call. Without the spread, it would just put the returned *array* into the new array, so the result of calling `protoTree(d)` would be `[c, [b, [a, [Object.prototype, []]]]]`. Btw, `protoTree` can also be implemented without spread.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [isPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) for this use case

Comment: this method compares objects, but if i don't know that a, b, c exist, how can i use ``isPrototypeOf()``?

Comment: so at first check whether they exist or not then do the further checks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Using `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()` is the way to do this

```js
function Person() {}
function Child() {}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

const child = new Child();

console.log(Person.prototype.isPrototypeOf(child));

console.log(Child.prototype.isPrototypeOf(child));
```

More about `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf)